# Auto restart rake task if it give exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task, god

I have a rake task that must be always run. But sometimes this task can fail. And I need auto restart it? I think I need use [God gem](http://godrb.com/) or maybe there are other ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case [God gem](http://godrb.com) is what I need, thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on your problem, but how about pure Ruby solution:

```
begin
  puts "Start"
  raise "BOOOM"
rescue Exception => e
  puts e.message
  sleep(2)
  retry
end
```

Just retry you begin block each time you catch an exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ubuntu you can use upstart quite easily with a config like this:

```
start on startup
stop on shutdown

pre-start script
   cd /var/www/my-app/current
end script

script
   exec RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake my_task_name
end script
```

Read more here: http://www.stackednotion.com/blog/2012/02/09/easy-rails-daemons-with-upstart/